# scrolless but draggable widget

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I’m willing to create a widget that draw graphics using OpenGL that doesn’t have a scroll but you can drag it to show the rest of the graphic. This image describes more or less what I’m talking about:

[image: widget]

As you can see there’s an arrow which points the direction that the user can drag and the rest of the graphic is showing.

From where I can start? Is there a tutorial or example that has something similar?

Comment: I think i'd go with an OpenGL camera that moves along the graph (transformation matrix that moves the graph) and completely bypass Qt scrolling features.

Comment: It might work, I will try it out. Thanks @Uroc327

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such widget already exists in Qwt library, additional tool based on Qt.

Qwt: http://qwt.sourceforge.net/index.html

QwtPlotPanner: http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_panner.html

example of usage:

```
QwtPlotPanner *d_panner = new QwtPlotPanner( ui->qwtPlot->canvas() );
d_panner->setMouseButton( Qt::LeftButton );
```

where `ui->qwtPlot` is a `QwtPlot` - widget for plotting.

Comment: Amazing, I will check for examples and how to implement this better.

Comment: @MrAlmighty Note: Qwt is really powerful tool and has much more than just plotting but it is a third-party library but it great works with Qt

Comment: The real propose is to study and try to implement my own, even simpler than Qwt's plotting. It's totally reinventing the well but I need to understand how it works.